# Can I connect two QTcpSocket in different networks?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

Can I connect between only local machine or can connect to another network?

Comment: If you have a suitable connection, and firewall rules permitting, you can even establish a socket connection to the International Space Station.

Comment: Yes you can....

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Yes, you can !

**Long answer**

What you're trying to achieve is called a Peer-to-Peer (P2P) connection (see the [Wikipedia page for more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer#Routing_and_resource_discovery)).

So first of all, it will depend on the network protocol you will be using. Do you want to connect two clients over the Internet (IP - Internet Protocol)? Or over Bluetooth, NFC or anything else?

Assuming you want to use IP, the difficulty of getting it to work depends on your networks. If you have a fixed public IP for each client, it's all going to be pretty straight forward.
If you don't, it gets a bit more complicated, depending on the case. If you have access to the router of each network, you can the redirect a specific port on each side to point to you client, in the [subnetwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

Otherwise, you will have to learn about [NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal). Since most routers create a subnet and assign non-public addresses to their clients.

Give us more details about your network architecture so we can give you more precise advice.

Cheers,

D